# Need Help Getting File From Recorded Video Uri

Tags: java, android

I have two activities. `Activity1` opens `Activity2`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_VIDEO_RESULT)
```

`Activity2` uses a `MediaRecorder` to allow the user to capture video. First, I prepare the `File` in `onCreate`:

```
 mRecordedFile = getOutputMediaFile(this, MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
```

The method used here is borrowed from Google's example as is how I create the file:

```
 private static File getOutputMediaFile(Context context, int type){
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");

        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
```

I set that as the output `File`:

`mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mRecordedFile.getAbsolutePath());`

After the user is done with the camera, this is the return `Intent`:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(mRecordedFile);
String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString());
String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

So, back in `Activity1`, I retrieve this `Uri` in the `onActivityResult` method, with `data` just being the return `Intent`:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
```

So far, so good it seems. The `Uri` looks something like this:

`file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mycameraapp.demo/files/Pictures/MyCameraApp/VID_20180713_091027.mp4`

Eventually, I try to retrieve this and convert it back into a `File` because I need to upload it to a server. Here are the relevant bits:

```
 String filePath = uri.getPath();
 File file = new File(filePath);
```

The `File` this creates is blank, with a length of 0. I've been beating my head against the wall in this for a but and feel like I must be missing something obvious. Any advice?

Comment: `"[...] convert it back into a File because I need to upload it to a server"` - you dont need a `File` - what you need is just `InputStream`, read `ContentResolver` API docs on how to get it

Comment: I may not need `File` per se, but even if I change the last bit of code to this: `InputStream inputStream = getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);`, `inputStream.available()` reads as 0. So, I think the issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: I'm an idiot. It had nothing to do with any of this. I posted the reason below and answers why things were coming back "" and 0 instead of null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know, you should probably post all the code. What's probably happening isn't even related to the bits of code you posted. You are probably setting the output file again right after the user hits the stop recording button, thus overwriting the file they just made.

Sorry, guys. Mental glitch on my part. Please ignore.